# In my project I have two table one is stream another is branch, stream_id on branch page?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

`stream_id` is a foreign key in the branch table, I can click on the branch and directly go on add branch option. How can we get `stream_id` on the branch page for saving in the database with a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass stream_id from View to Controller in a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stream_id)
```

And in Controller, use the stream_id to get Stream and create associated Branch and then the foreign key will be automatically inserted.

```
using (var dataContext = new DBContextModel())
{
   var stream = dataContext.YourStreamDBSet.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == stream_id);
   stream.BranchList.Add(YourNewBranch);
   dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is assuming you are using EF.